# What is the meaning of the input variables when registering a new group?

Tags: asch

The (smart) contract function to register a new group looks as follows:

```
async registerGroup(name, members, min, max, m, updateInterval) {
...
}
```

What is the meaning of `min`,`max`, `m` and `updateInterval` in the above?

Answer (score 0):

`name` is the name of the group

`members` is the list of member added to the group at initialization. The list contains probably the public keys.

`min` and `max` set the minimum and maximum number of members, `min` should be >= `3`.

`m` that is the minimum vote weight a request transaction must get.

`m` sets the total weight of votes required to activate a group transaction <strike>the group</strike>, the check can be found in the `asch/src/contract/group.js` file in the `activate()` function:

```
const group = await app.sdb.load('Group', account.name)
if (totalWeight < group.m) return 'Vote weight not enough'
```

Notice that `m` also can be set when adding a new group member with `group.addMember`:

```
async addMember(address, weight, m) {
   ...
     if (m) {
      const group = await app.sdb.load('Group', this.sender.name)
      if (!group) return 'Group not found'
      group.m = m
      app.sdb.update('Group', { m }, { name: this.sender.name })
     }
   ...
}
```

The `updateInterval` is unclear till now. Possible related to the time a group member should lock it's XAS.